# Is it possible to reduce the default varchar size in catalog_product_flat? (M2)

Tags: flat-catalog, eav-attributes, flat-indexer, varchar

I have a seemingly common problem. With too many custom attributes that are necessary and no way to change them in a way that would make the use of the default flat catalog possible I am searching for another solution.

Magento by default sets the size of attributes stored as varchar in flat tables to 255, which in my case is unnecessarily long. I could totally live with a size of 65, which would also bypass the MySQL limitation problem.

I have found hints on how to adjust Magento 1 in that way but not a single clue on how to do that with Magento 2. What I would like to know is:

- Wether or not this is possible at all, e.g. where to find the sizing in the code,
- And if it is, what kind of problems could emerge doing it.

UPDATE:
I have found a way to do it, which seems really convenient. I added

```
if ($fieldName != "description" && $columnLength > 200){
   $columnLength = 65;
}
```

right before

```
$table->addColumn($fieldName, $fieldProp['type'], $columnLength, $columnDefinition, $columnComment);
```

in `Magento/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/FlatTableBuilder`

Creating the flat table now works like a charm, but my second question remains: What kind of implications could this have?

Comment: I did actually do exactly what you suggested above in UPDATE for exact same reasons (flat catalogue wouldnt work) however I had wiered issues, I think related products stopped showing prices and names in some cases. I didnt have loads of time to debug at the time (may have been a simple fix) so reverted but yeah I had issues doing that although reindex worked with flat catalogue after the mod.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. We have had it in production since I posted the update. Related products though don't cause any problems. But I have to add that description is not the only exception I made. I also added short description, img urls and similar things to the list.

Comment: Interesting, glad it worked for you i may give it another go yeah i did a fair few also not just description too. I wonder what my issue was!